# Is it possible to make a list of numbers from 1 to n using a loop in python 3.6, then print it?

Tags: python, list, loops, range

I am creating a board game with python, and i need to use numbers as coordinates. There are 121 coordinates, and i want to make a list for it. But i don't want to type all the numbers from 1 to 121. I found this code:

```
coordinates = [range(1,121)]
```

I tried to print it, but it didn't return the numbers from 1 to 121, just the actual function: range(1,121). What happened??

Comment: I think you are looking for `[*range(1,121)]` or `list(range(1,121))`?. **Please note that `range(1,121)` does not produce a list, instead it returns a `rangeobject`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 coordinates=[]
    for i in range(1,122):
            coordinates.append(i)
    print(coordinates)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I accidently put the print in the for loop, and it overloaded the shell, but it works! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The solution you have found will work for Python-2.x only.

You can achieve the same in many ways as described below:

Using list comprehension:

```
[i for i in range(1,121)]
```

unpacking range with `*`:

```
[*range(1,121)]
```

using `numpy`:

```
import numpy
numpy.arange(1, 121)
```

Note: 
you mentioned in your question that you want to print numbers 1 to 121 (1 to n) to generate nth value you need to use n+1 th value instead of nth

Answer (score -1):

range didn't generate list or tuple, you can try:

```
coordinates = list(range(1,121))
```

The description in python doc：

> The advantage of the range type over a regular list or tuple is that a
>   range object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no
>   matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the
>   start, stop and step values, calculating individual items and
>   subranges as needed).

Comment: isn't that mine?